# The Sum of Consecutive Numbers in Python

Tags: python

What I have to do is get the user input and add consecutive numbers starting with one using a loop until the sum equals or exceeds the input. It's an exercise, so I'm trying to do this without using the condition True or importing any functions. Just a simple while loop.

This is what I've got.

```
num = int(input("Limit:"))
base = 0
while base < num:
    base += base + 1
    print(base)
```

When I input 21, the printout is 1
3
7
15
31

No idea how to fix. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Sorry for not specifying, the expected output should only be the final number, that which exceeds or equals the input. So for instance, if input is 10, output should be 10. If input is 18, output should be 21.

Comment: what is your expected output and input. add that in question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should calculate consecutive numbers in dedicated variable

Try this

```
limit = int(input("Limit:"))
base = 0
number = 1
while base < limit:
    base += number
    number += 1
print(base)
```

Comment: Thanks @Eugenij. Sorry for not specifying, the expected output should only be the final number, that which exceeds or equals the input. So for instance, if input is 10, output should be 10. If input is 18, output should be 21.

Comment: @emt1619 Adjust answer to your edit. 

Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Step through what your code is doing, when given `21` as an input.

```
num = int(input("Limit:"))
base = 0
while base < num:
    base += base + 1
    print(base)
```

We know our initial state is:

```
num = 21
base = 0
```

`base` is less than `21`, so we'll add `base` to `1`, then add all of that to `base` with `+=`.

```
num = 21
base = 1
```

Now, let's keep going:

```
num = 21
base = 1

num = 21
base = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3

num = 21
base = 3 + 3 + 1 = 7

num = 21
base = 7 + 7 + 1 = 15

number = 21
base = 15 + 15 + 1 = 31
```

If you want to sum a range of numbers, well... Python makes that really straightforward using a while loop. We need a counter (which we'll update on each loop), the end number, and a sum variable (the name `sum` is already a built-in function).

```
num = int(input("Limit:"))
counter = 0
sumNums = 0
while counter < num:
    sumNums += counter
    count += 1
    print(sumNums)
```

Or we can just sum a range.

```
print(sum(range(1, num)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I forgot to mention originally, Sorry for not specifying, the expected output should only be the final number, that which exceeds or equals the input. So for instance, if input is 10, output should be 10. If input is 18, output should be 21. It basically needs to add (1 + 2 + 3 etc) all the way up to or exceeding the number, and then print just the result of the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Just because I like math:

```
num = int(input("Limit:"))
for n in range(1,num):
    s = n * (n + 1) / 2
    if s >= num:
        break
print(int(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your expected output to only be the final number, simply unindent the print statement:

```
limit = int(input("Limit:"))

base = 0
num = 1

# Each time base is less than limit, add base by num (At the first iteration num is 1), and add num by 1
while base < limit:
    base += num 
    num += 1
print(base)
```

Sample output:

```
>>> Limit: 18
21
```

```
>>> Limit: 10
10
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to stop before it prints.

```
number = int(input("Limit: "))
x = 1
y = 1
while y < number:
    x +=1
    y +=x
    
print(y)
```

Answer (score -1):

You must do or `base = base + 1` or `bas += 1` not both otherwise you sum  `base + (base + 1)` that is wrong.

But you can do it also quickly in the same way:

```
sum(range(1, num + 1))
```

Comment: This is not what they asked about. They want to go until the *sum* equals or exceeds the supplied limit.