# The Sum of Consecutive Numbers

Tags: python, loops

I have to write a program which asks the user to type in a limit. The program then calculates the sum of consecutive numbers (1 + 2 + 3 + ...) until the sum is at least equal to the limit set by the user.

In addition to the result it should also print out the calculation performed. I should do this with only a while loop, no lists or True conditionals.

```
limit = int(input("Limit:"))
base = 0
num = 0
calc = " "
while base < limit:
    base += num
    num += 1
    calc += f" + {num}"
print(base)
print(f"The consecutive sum: {calc} = {base}")
```

So for example, if the input is 10, the output should be 10 and underneath that should be "The consecutive sum: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10." If the input is 18, the output should be 21 and underneath that should be "The consecutive sum: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21."

Right now I can get it to print the final result (base) and have gotten it to print out the calculation, but it prints out one integer too many. If the input is 10, it prints out 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 when it should stop before the 5.

Comment: What have you tried? Ignore the rest of your program. It's irrelevant to the question you're asking. I give you `num` at the end of the loop, you don't care where it came from, and neither do I. How do you print `1 + 2 + ... + num`?

Comment: Major clue :) If you use `print("something", end ="")`  you can print without it going on to a new line each time.

Comment: there area couple of way to make such string, one of the them is to build it alongside your other calculation, like for example `mystring += " +" + str(num)`  and of course initialize the string variable accordingly

Comment: How is this different to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70475666/1324033)?

Comment: @sayse This time I need to actually show the calculation.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I tried this `limit = int(input("Limit:"))
base = 0
num = 0
calc = " "
while base < limit:
    base += num
    num += 1
    calc += f" + {num}"
print(base)
print(f"The consecutive sum: {calc} = {base}")`

Only problem is, it prints out 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 when the input is 10 when it should stop before the 5.

Comment: @emt1619. I'd like to help, but you need to ask the right question (which I already showed you). Please don't post relevant code in the comments.

Comment: Also, the whole calculation can be replaced with a triangle number computation, which requires no loops

Comment: Move line `calc += f" + {num}"` two lines up... It really will be a benefit for you, if you try several things on your own, before giving up, to learn and understand how stuff works. Just a kind suggestion. In this case `num` is already 5 when you add it to `calc`, you need to add it before it becomes 5, hence before line `num += 1`.

Comment: No worries @MadPhysicist, got the answer below.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that came to my mind is concatenating values for each iteration:

```py
limit = int(input("Limit:"))
base = 0
num = 1
num_total = 0
calculation = 'The consecutive sum: '
while base < limit:
    calculation += f"{num} + "
    base += num
    num += 1

print(f"{calculation[:-3]} = {base}")
print(base)

#> Limit:18
## The consecutive sum: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21
## 21
```

The other way is printing value on each iteration without new line in the end (but you have additional `+` sign in the end here):

```py
limit = int(input("Limit:"))
base = 0
num = 1
num_total = 0
print('The consecutive sum: ', end='')
while base < limit:
    print(f"{num} + ", end='')
    base += num
    num += 1

print(f"= {base}")
print(base)

#> Limit:18
## The consecutive sum: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + = 21
## 21
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much. I'm curious why you need the [:-3] to get rid of the extra +?

Comment: Yep, as you don't know which iteration will be the last one, you have an extra in the end.

Answer (score 4):

I would avoid the `while` loop and use `range` instead. You can derive the value of the last term with arithmetic.

If the last term is , then the sum [will be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) (+1)/2, which must be less or equal to the input limit. Resolving this equation to  given the limit, we get that the  is <sub>⌊</sub>√(1 + 8⋅limit) − 1) / 2<sub>⌋</sub>

So then the program can be:

```
limit = int(input("Limit:"))

n = int(((1 + 8 * limit) ** 0.5 - 1) / 2)

formula = " + ".join(map(str, range(1, n + 1)))
total  = n * (n + 1) // 2
print(f"The consecutive sum: {formula} = {total}")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more efficient way to write this but this was what came to mind...

```
sum = 0
long_output = []

for i in range(limit + 1):
  sum += i
  long_output.append(str(i))

print("The consecutive sum: {} = {}".format(' + '.join(long_output), sum))
```

Keep putting stuff in an list and then join them afterwards.  `i` has to be casted to a `str` type since join is just for strings

NOTE: the output starts at `0` to account for `limit` being potentially 0 (I don't know what your constraints are, if any)

EDIT: made updates based on @Copperfield's recommendation

Comment: no need to also append the plus sign, you can join them with `" + "`

Comment: That's right!  Thanks!

Comment: the OP doesn't want the sum of the numbers from 0 until `limit` but until the first time the accumulative sum of those numbers is bigger or equal to limit

Comment: LOL.  RIght again!  (reading is hard -_-")  Happy holidays!

Answer (score 0):

You are/were very close. Try rearranging the follow of execution in your while statements. I also find this assignment hard. Try moving you calc line as the first statement after your 'while'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

One other way is to add an `if` statement:

```
if base< num :
   calc += f" + {num}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Write your solution here
number = 0
base = 0
ntotal = ""
limit = int(input("Limit:"))
while base < limit: 
    number += 1  # increment the consecutive numbers
    if base == 0:
        ntotal = f"{ntotal}{number}"  # ignore the first null string of ntotal ""
    else:
        ntotal = f"{ntotal} + {number}"  # concat the strings
    base += number  # increment after the if statement, else it will always add the null string and give as +1+2...
    
print(f"The consecutive sum: {ntotal} = {base}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a example to print the calculation

```
limit = int(input("Limit:"))
base = 0
num = 1
num_total = 0
msg = ""
while base < limit:
    msg = msg + str(num) + "+"
    base += num
    num += 1
msg =  msg[:-1] + "=" + str(limit) 
print(msg)
```

if `limit = 21` then the output would be

```
1+2+3+4+5+6=21
```